# Why does "Integer.TYPE" show error in annotation "attribute value must be constant"

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

I've created an annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD )
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
public @interface Test
{
    Class something();
}
```

But when I call it with `Integer.TYPE` (for the return type of an int), it shows the error.

```
public class TestA
{
    @Test(Integer.TYPE)
    public int id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Class` is not commensurate with the value `Integer.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7)

> **It is a compile-time error if the element type is not commensurate
>   with the element value. An element type `T` is commensurate with an
>   element value `V` if and only if one of the following is true:**
>
> - [...]
> - **If `T` is `Class` or an invocation of `Class` (§4.5), then `V` is a class
>     literal (§15.8.2).**

From the source code of `Integer`

```
public static final Class<Integer>  TYPE = (Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");
```

The expression `Integer#TYPE` is not a class literal. `Integer.class` or `int.class` would work, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `int.class` instead of `Integer.TYPE`:

```
@Test(int.class)
```